# Is it possible to port User DSN's from one laptop to another?

Tags: dsn

My company sent laptop upgrades to some employees.  I have some User DSN's on my old laptop that I need to move to the new one.  They are DB2 DSNs, and it looks like the old driver is 1111_64R1 and the new one is 1155_64.  I copied the db2cli.ini file, but it didn't work.  Our help desk doesn't have the answer, because they mostly just read from a script.  Yes, I rebooted the machine, etc...

I looked in db2cli.ini and it doesn't store the host name or port number in it.  I'm assuming that info is stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The "User DSNs" are stored in the Registry, at `HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\`.

(Use the "Search" function in Regedit, or use SysInternals Process Monitor to find out which files and/or Registry keys a process is looking in.)